# How to run multiple jars in springboot when i deploy microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

Please help me to deploy microservice without using dockers,and how can I run multiple service using single command

Comment: Pls describe a bit more what you want to achieve. What do you mean by running multiple services? Multiple instances of same service or different services? Where do you want to deploy it?

Comment: You can write a simple sh script to go to each jar of your microservice and write command to run that jar. (gradle clean bootRun)

Comment: yes can you help me with that sh script @AmitB10

Comment: can you help me exmple of sh script @AmitB10

Comment: Yes, I will post the example shortly..

Answer (score 0):

Spring boots fat jar enables you to just start the jar by using Java - jar command.
Just write a script, that does it on your server.